# How is there a 3.1 gb filesystem WITHOUT hard drives in Ubuntu Live

Tags: live-cd

I am running Ubuntu live **without** any hard drives installed in my pavillion and there is a 3.1 GB file system. It is not on the DVD-r that I put Ubuntu live on. It also appears that someone is manipulating the info and tweaking my live session. How is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Magic!

More seriously, a few things - firstly that the filesystem on the disk is compressed with [squashfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SquashFS), any changes are temporarily stored in a ramdisk, and lost when you reboot. All this is abstracted away into a single file system through [unionfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS)

The 3.1gb filessytem you see is the unionfs file system, and squashfs makes it possible to fit all that into the livedisk.

Like I said, its magic ;)

Comment: thx for the answer but i am still confused. now when i log into live my cd ejects when i click on the wireless icon. My only disk is my cd/dvd it shows 788.7 gb in properties. then there is a little icon when i open my home folder that looks like a hd, properties 3.1 gb. that is some kind of magic to me.

Comment: I feel inept, i am trying to click on 'setting a password' the words push in but I can't find a way to set my password. i would like to wrap this up for the night but want to be able to access the site tomorrow. any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Easier explanation: Ubuntu creates a virtual hard-drive in your computer's [Random Access Memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory).